# Get the value of dropdown and textbox value in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Please help me. I need to get the value of the textbox and the value of the dropdown list.

So far i was able to get the value of the dropdown list using this code

```
public class DropdownOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

public class DropdownOrderVM
    {
        public int DropdownId { get; set; }
        public string SearchValue { get; set; }
        public List<DropdownOrder> DropdownList { get; set; }
    }

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var vm = new DropdownOrderVM();
            vm.DropdownList = new List<DropdownOrder>
            {
                new DropdownOrder { Id = 1, Value = "1" },
                new DropdownOrder { Id = 2, Value = "2" },
                new DropdownOrder { Id = 3, Value = "3" }
            };


            return View(vm);
        }
```

And this is the view code

```
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="DropdownId"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DropdownList,"Id","Value"))">
                <option>Please select one</option>
            </select>
           
       
                <input type="search" name="search" id="search"  asp-for="SearchValue"  placeholder="Search" class="form-control" aria-label="Search">
```

and this is my controller which call called when the button submit is clicked

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(DropdownOrderVM model)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I can only get the value of the dropdown. But i added the code in the view

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="search"  asp-for="SearchValue" >
```

So why does my code doesn't return the user input in the textbox?

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Can you post your whole view pls, including model part

Comment: You can delete the code `name="search"`,or you can change to `name=SearchValue`,it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitly giving name & id to your text box which doesn't match the model field. Remove these 3 attributes from your search textbox: **type="search" name="search" id="search"**. Tag helper **asp-for** will do this for you.